# Import react-table data into google spreedsheet with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, google-sheets, export, react-table

I am using react-table for displaying data fetched from backend, and also I can download the data as a csv file in the local.
My question is about how can I download/export react-table data into google spreadsheets programmatically ?
Users login into application via their google account and all have access to google spreadsheets. I just need to export data into there.
I have checked react-google-sheets package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-sheets, but this library needs to have a spreedsheet id as a parameter . I expect that application creates a new spreedsheet for each download.

Thanks in advance